# Where is Spring 3 MVC in REST web-app example download?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I saw springsource.org had not spring 3 in rest web-app sample,where is download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Spring samples are on the [official SVN repository](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/). The [MVC Showcase application](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-showcase/) should get you started on REST web applications with spring mvc:

```
svn co https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-showcase/ mvc-showcase
```

If you want to work on the client side, Spring provides [RestTemplates](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/) for accessing other rest services from your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven you can simply add it to your pom. If not, you can manually download whichever sub-project you need from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework).

Comment: I want to download a spring3 mvc in rest web-app example

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any rest example with spring MVC 3. The @SessionAttributes annotation breaks REST idea.

Answer (score 1):

vn co https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-showcase/ mvc-showcase
It's not rest application cause it uses @SessiontAttributes annotation. But REAST requires transfer state via URL

Answer (score 1):

They are now only on github afaik :

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase